Cache libraries in C++
Are there any popular cache libraries in C++ with persistent support like Embedded Ehcache? The following are the needs for our cache libraries.

Multiple values in a single record. So, complex collection support is needed.
In-memory with file-based Persistence-backed.(DB suggestions would be helpful but prefers file-based)
Embedded caching library.
Concurrent with a large set of data read, write and updation would be handled by this.
Active community or clear API docs would be helpful.

While searching through open-source libraries, Most lack persistence or are not embedded. For example, Cachelib would persist data only during shutdown. But we need it to be backed during the cache process, because of the large data set which needs to be persisted if a certain count is reached and then loaded to in-memory when needed. FasterKV is a key-value store and also documentation of C++ API is not great.
